# Html support in Google Apps Script UI Services Widgets?

Tags: gwt, google-apps, google-apps-script

As far I can tell, none of the Widgets in UI Services can display formatted HTML.  GWT provides [RichTextArea.setHTML()](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RichTextArea.html#setHTML%28java.lang.String%29) and [Label.HTML](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html) to display formatted HTML, but these aren't available through the App Script UI Services.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is coming soon. Look at the google response on [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=175#c23):

> Comment 21 by project member asora...@google.com, Feb 7
>
> Hey Everyone,
>
> Quick update: A support for a subset of HTML tags is going to be added
>   to UiApp within 2-3 weeks!
>
> Best, Anton

**UPDATE**
As of Mar 7 this feature has been implemented. This is the list for supported tags:

```
B
BLOCKQUOTE
BODY
BR
CENTER
CAPTION
CITE
CODE
DIV
EM
H1
H2
H3
H4
H5
H6
HR
I
LABEL
LEGEND
LI
OL
P
SPAN
STRONG
SUB
SUP
TABLE
TBODY
TD
THEAD
TITLE
TR
TT
UL
```

*Related docs:* https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_html